Is there a way to use filter inside user defined function?
I wanted to use a variable inside a user-defined function. I don't get the desired output by doing:
library(dplyr)
mtcars |> filter(vs == 0) |> nrow() # 18

get_parim <- function(var) {
  n <- mtcars |> filter({{var}} == 0) |> nrow()
  print(n)
}

get_parim("vs") # 0

Any ideas?

get_parim(vs). Don't quote the argument.

get_parim = function(var) mtcars |> dplyr::filter( {{var}} == 0) |> nrow(); get_parim(vs) works

Does this answer your question? Pass a string as variable name in dplyr::filter - if you want to pass a string you need filter(!!sym(var) == 0).

Also, including the data argument may seem logical: get_parim <- function(data, var){ n <- data |> .... Then: get_parim(mtcars, vs).

... and add an explicit check: does var exists in colnames(data), e.g. get_parim = \(data, var) { stopifnot(var %in% colnames(data)); data |> dplyr::filter(!!sym(var) == 0) |> nrow() }; get_parim(mtcars, "vs")?

Also: filter(get(var) == 0). Then get_parim("vs") # 18

See Programming with dplyr if you want to understand how do this properly.
